# 'NoneType' object is not callable - python decorators

Tags: python, nonetype

I am trying to understand Python decorators.
Tried this examples from FluentPython book. (Example 7.2, for reference(

```
# Using Decorators
registry = []

def register(func):
    print(f'running registry -> {func}')
    registry.append(func)


@register
def f1():
    print('running f1()')


@register
def f2():
    print('running f2()')


@register
def f3():
    print('running f3()')


def main():
    print('running registry')
    print(f'registry -> {registry}')
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('running main()')
    main()
```

But when i run this script it gives me error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/abcdef/Documents/FluentPython/NLP_C1_W1_lecture_nb_01.py", line 3, in

Examples.main()
File "C:\Users\abcdef\Documents\FluentPython\Examples.py", line 25, in main
f1()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Unable to understand why this is the case.
I am simply calling the functions - f1, f2 and f3 using f1(), f2() and f3(). I expect to get 'running f1()' etc printed out, but instead i get an error.

Could someone please elaborate why this is the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`register` annotation is wrapping the functions, it's basically the same as doing

```
register(f1)
```

and since `register` doesn't have `return` statement it returns `None`, so `f1()` is actually an attempt to invoke `None` as a function.

You can solve it by adding `return func` to `register`

```
def register(func):
    print(f'running registry -> {func}')
    registry.append(func)
    return func
```